# Path specification for database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I need to specify a path in a database.yml file that isn't in the application I'm using.

My initial attempts were unsuccessful, and my search terms unclear so I haven't turned up a definitive way of specifying a specific file path outside of the rails application, yet.

How do I do this? Or rather what is the best way to do this, in a non database driver specific manner (as I'll be using sqlite, mysql and postgresql in my development/testing)?. I have the basic gist from simple applications, but my environment is getting a bit more complicated and I need to centralize a number of db to one, and then specify this per application.

Comment: After more searching, this pertains mostly to sqlite db...still having issue specifying a shared sqlite db outside of the rails root

Comment: Deployment tools like capistrano usually solve this with a symbolic link from `/my/path/to/the/real/db.sqlite3` to `/rails/root/db/my_db/sqlite3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of erb inserted into the database.yml db field indicating a path relative to rails root appears to work at first glance. So, 'use erb' is the first obvious answer.